# C# Call class using System.Threading.Timer from Winforms interval fails

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

i have a winform app that uses other class(in seprated DLL)
it looks like:

```
public Form1()

    {

        foo = new Foo(2500, this.refreshGrid);
     }
    private void refreshGrid(List<int> source)
    {
        dgvDrivers.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        dgvDrivers.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;

        dgvDrivers.SynchronizedInvoke(() => dgvDrivers.DataSource = source);
        dgvDrivers.AutoResizeColumns();
     }
```

and the Extension method:

```
   public static void SynchronizedInvoke(this ISynchronizeInvoke sync,  Action action)
    {
         // If the invoke is not required, then invoke here and get out.
          if (!sync.InvokeRequired)
           {
               // Execute action.
               action();

              // Get out.
               return;
           }

           // Marshal to the required context.
          sync.Invoke(action, new object[] { });
       }
```

now i have a class that init new System.Threading.Timer to run once at specfic time:

```
public CreateTimer(int dueTime)
{
      new System.Threading.Timer(SchudleStatusChange, null, dueTime, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
  }
```

Back to UI - there is button that calls CreateTimer() 10 times per click
but the timer is invoked less times then i expected.
I guess it something realted to using winforms and the invoke of main thread.

any ideads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't hang on to a reference to your timer, so the garbage collector gobbled it up and shut it down.

> [As long as you are using a Timer, you must keep a reference to it. As with any managed object, a Timer is subject to garbage collection when there are no references to it. The fact that a Timer is still active does not prevent it from being collected.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: OK,But when i called the same code from Console application this class worked fine...

Comment: So that suggests that the GC didn't run in your Console. Garbage collection happens at indeterminate times, depending on memory load etc.